# Close popup browser on auth results

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, spotify

I'm using Ionic and I'm trying to auth with [Spotify](https://github.com/Festify/cordova-spotify/blob/develop/www/cordova-spotify.js). I have the the authentication screen popup when a user clicks "Login with Spotify" but when they click connect on the login screen the popup browser isn't closing. I have deeplinks set up and I'm using that as my redirect uri, the console logs that it's successful but nothing happens.

Here is my ionic info:

```
global packages:

@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0

System:

Node       : v8.1.2
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.3.3 Build version 8E3004b
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 5.0.4
```

When I click "connect" on the Spotify popup screen the console shows this:

[image]

But the popup window is never closed and the promise I'm using is never returned. Here is the code:

```
// This is in my Spotify service
connect(): Promise<any> {

     return this.spotify.authenticate(this.options)

}

// This is on my home page (it's what's called when you click "Login with Spotify"
spotifyConnect() {

    this._spotifyService.connect().then(

      result => console.log('hi!', result) //this is never returned
    );

}
```

My redirect uri is `turn://app/home` and my deeplinks config looks like this:

```
this._deepLinks.routeWithNavController(this.navChild, {
    '/': HomePage,
    '/home/:results': HomePage,
    '/playlist-find': 'playlist-find'
  }).subscribe((match) => {
    console.log('Successfully routed', match);
  }, (nomatch) => {
    console.log('Unmatched Route', nomatch);
  });
```

I've tried setting my redirect uri to `window.location.href` but that just opens the app in the popup browser.

Thank you!